# What is Remote debugging in .Net?

Tags: debugging

I have to debug my project with server DLL using Romote Debugging but I don't know how to do that. Anyone know about Remote debugging and process to do it in visual studio 2010.

Comment: This is explained in detail [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa(v=vs.100).aspx). Set up msvsmon.exe on the remote server and make sure you've got the source for the same version of the dll on your local machine during the debugging session.